# How to prevent turn off a screen?

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I would like to don't turn off a screen after specific time of inactivity in my intel xdk application if user is in a given function. 
It would be also fine if the whole application wouldn't agree to turn off. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [insomnia plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()">keep awake</button>
<button onclick="window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain()">allow sleep again</button>
```